# How to set default time in Mobiscroll?

Tags: jquery, mobiscroll

The main problem is that the project is a bit old and I can't update `Mobiscroll` and also don’t know the current version of it... My code looks like this:

```
jQuery('#select-time').mobiscroll().time({
    'timeFormat': 'HH:ii:ss',
    'timeWheels': 'HHiiss',
});
```

I need to set time to `00:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setDate](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/2-13-2/datetime#!method-setDate) function by passing an arbitrary date and 00:00:00 as the time

```
$('#demo').mobiscroll().time({
    timeFormat: 'HH:ii:ss',
    timeWheels: 'HHiiss'
});

$('#demo').mobiscroll('setDate', new Date(2015, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), true);
```